# Excel VBA: Why does the ColorIndex of a blank cell appear to be -4142

Tags: excel, vba

I have always learned that the colorIndex property of a cell is a value up to 56, where white normally is 2.
This was the case in my file when I checked last time.
When I check the colorIndex of my empty, white, cells. It turns out to be -4142. Anyone knows what is happening here?

I'm checking the colorIndex with this code:

```
Function ColorIndex(CellColorIndex As Range)

ColorIndex = CellColorIndex.Interior.ColorIndex
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `Interior.ColorIndex` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex):

> The color is specified as an index value into the current color palette, or as one of the following `XlColorIndex` constants: `xlColorIndexAutomatic` or `xlColorIndexNone`.

`-4142` corresponds to `xlColorIndexNone` as noted in the `xlColorIndex` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolorindex).